# Why does bufio.Scanner only Read 101 times before giving up?

Tags: go

I have an io.Reader that occasionally receives data. I set up a Scanner to read until a new line. However, through debugging, I noticed that bufio.Scanner.Scan only calls Read 101 times before never calling it again. Why? I need for it to call until it recieves input, no matter how long that takes.

I can get around this by using `Reader.ReadLine`. Is this intended?

Comment: From [the documentation of bufio.Scanner](https://pkg.go.dev/bufio#Scanner): *"Programs that need more control over error handling or large tokens, or must run sequential scans on a reader, should use bufio.Reader instead."*